# Accessing dynamic div id inside ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to receive data from php server. The data is received in json format. To display this data I am creating dynamic divs with unique ids. I have appended the dynamic divs in an already structured html.

Now while spitting out the data using `("#"+dynamicid).html("data")`, I am unable to get the desired output.

Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var i = "kmapN"+data.id;
            $('<div class="kmapName">').append($('<div id="'+ i +'">'))
                                       .append($('</div></div>'))
                                       .appendTo('.new_content');
            $("#"+i).html(data.kname);
            }
      });
```

Here's the json output from the server:

```
{"id":2,"kname":"This is the title!"}
```

**Edit1:** 
If I don't use the dynamic id, I am getting the result. The problem is therefore in generating and accessing the dynamic id.

**Edit2:**
The idea here is to prevent javascript and html injection attacksby using ("#" + id).html("output") function of jquery.

Comment: can you please brief json result you're getting

Comment: Since `dataType` is not set we don't know if you really get json as result. Print the content of data please.

Comment: What result you get and what you want to get?

Comment: read jquery docs. if you want to access class name, use `$('.youClassName')....`

Comment: You don't need an id to do this job. If the id is not used for another purpose, then it can be omitted.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I have actually simplified the code to the segment where I am experiencing the problem. The id has usage in the code.

Comment: Your problem must be elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/h8ga6c4y/ works without issue. (The fact I'm not doing an AJAX call shouldn't matter. I've also simplified the chained appends you have.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  $('.kmapName').append('--Output you want to be rendered ---');
```

Answer (score 0):

your `dataType` must be defined.

create your dynamic div and append the variable to the main div

```
.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {

          var i = "kmapN"+data.id;
          var new_div ='<div class="kmapName"><div id="'+ i +'">'+ data.kname +'</div></div>';

            $(".new_content").append(new_div);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Should not must. From jQuery documentation: `The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response`.

Comment: @Debflav ok i will change my answer

Comment: @ArjunTuli i have changed the other parts of the code , please check it . .new_content div should be already in your HTML page

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya .new_content div is there and the code is working fine for non dynamically generated ids

Comment: @ArjunTuli have you tried my code ? , are you getting any errors

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya I just realised that the data that which will the outputted this way would be prone to javascript and html injection attacks. My main aim is to prevent them by using ("#" + id).html("output") function of jquery.